# Performance comparison LASSO vs. Tikhonov

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, least-squares

Tikhonov Regularization can be described as

$$
\min_g \| Yg - x\|_2^2 + \alpha \|g\|_2^2
$$

and LASSO can be described as:

$$
\min_g \| Yg - x\|_2^2 + \beta \|g\|_1
$$

Is there any way to relate the resulting error (e.g. mean squared error) between these two?

The answer depends on $Y$, $x$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but is there anything that can be said if either of these have certain forms?

Comment: That's not Tikhonov regularization . You should replace $\|g\|_2$ with $\frac{1}{2}\|g\|_2^2$.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to square all the L2 norms, I fixed the question. The 1/2-factor can be moved into $\alpha$

Comment: You can think of the as a MAP estimators with different priors. What do you mean by Mean Squared Error? They don't try to minimize it (At least no only it).